# Solve for variable in given probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let's say I have this distribution:

```
f(x) = k/(x^5) for x > 1, and 0 for x <= 1
```

How would I solve for the variable `k`?

Normally I would have an upper bound on `x` like `1 < x < 5` or something, in this case `5` is the upper bound, and I would solve for `k` like this:

```
1 = definite integral from 1 to 5 of k/(x^5) dx
```

So how to solve in this case since I don't have an upper bound for x?

Comment: The density is defined on $x>1$ and 0 elsewhere. So you should be integrating on $1<x<\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $\displaystyle \int_{1}^\infty kx^{-5} = 1\implies \dfrac{k}{4} = 1\implies k = 4$ .

Comment: Ok thanks. So when I solve the definite integral and plug in positive infinity for `x`, what should I get?

Comment: how was it that plugging in infinity for the first integral solution equaled zero or canceled out?